# How can i change the order of fields in a composite primary key in core data?

Tags: core-data, composite-key

I created three entities in my data model: `Actor`, `Movie` and `Studio`. All of them have attributes `name` and `rating`, one actor has multiple movies, one studio has multiple studios, and one movie can have multiple actors and multiple studios.

When I run the project, the relationship tables were created by follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Z_1MOVIES ( Z_1ACTORS INTEGER, Z_2MOVIES INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (Z_1ACTORS, Z_2MOVIES) );
CREATE TABLE Z_2STUDIOS ( Z_2MOVIES1 INTEGER, Z_3STUDIOS INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (Z_2MOVIES1, Z_3STUDIOS) );
```

The runtime of extracting actor (`[movie actors`]) is longer than extracting studios `[movie studios]`, I think it should be caused by the order of composite primary key in relationship table. If I can change the primary key as `(Z_2MOVIES, Z_1ACTORS)` in `Z_1MOVIES`, the performance should be better.

So, any ways to change the order of composite key in core data?

Answer (score 0):

May be you just need to alter your table schema.

```
ALTER TABLE `Z_1MOVIES` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (Z_2MOVIES, Z_1ACTORS);
```

If you are selecting actors by movie, you need index by Z_2MOVIES. Composite index can be used partially by its left part. This mean you can use index (a, b) as index (a), but you can not use it as index (b).